# Sudden Git error when trying to push my Rails to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, push

I got stuck with error when trying to push my app to heroku:

```
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to svpsample.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/svpsample.git
   ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/svpsample.git'
```

What is the cause? How to eliminate the problem?

Comment: Could you update with the full error message?

Comment: $ git push heroku
 ......
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to svpsample.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/svpsample.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/svpsample.git'

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the error in your stylesheet and javascript files .The error doesn't come in development mode .If you want to see the errors in development mode then do rake assets:precompile .You will see the errors  Resolve those and then deploy your project

Comment: I don't know I have tried so many suggested solutions, but I still hit the rock bottom. It work fine on my local computer.

Comment: did you do rake assets:precompile on your local and check the terminal whether the error was same or not

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari I have run this command and it doesn't show the error i got in deployment